# Live incremental Xampp backup on Windows Server 2003

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, xampp, backup

I'm running a Xampp server over Windows Server 2003 and I would like to back it up without stopping it.

I want it to be incremental and save everything but the software in itself. I mean I want to save the configuration files (apache, php, mysql), the htdocs folder and the database (MySQL) but not mysqld.exe for instance.

I already setted up an batch script that executes mysqldump but it's not incremental and not easy to restore for a newbie.

Ideally it would be compressed.

Thanks.